# sed regex syntax for multiple searches

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to find and replace a specific string within /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
`#PermitRootLogin yes` > `PermitRootLogin no`.
However I want to make sure I get almost any version of it (if that makes sense).

ex;

```
#PermitRootLogin yes
PermitRootLogin yes
#PermitRootLogin no
```

I am fairly new to bash, linux, unix etc and have really only been learning this stuff for the past 2 weeks so if possible, please explain to me like i'm brand new to linux/unix.
Thank you in advance.

So far i've tried 2 thing so far and neither of them seem to do what I need.

```
sed -E 's/(#|^)PermitRootLogin(yes|no)/PermitRootLogin no/' FILENAME
```

and

```
sed -E 's/(#/|^/)PermitRootlogin(yes/|no/)/PermitRootLogin no/' FILENAME
```

I was expecting all the lines in the example above to be changed to;

```
PermitRootLogin no
PermitRootLogin no
PermitRootLogin no
```

Answer (score 3):

This one's just missing a space

```
sed -E 's/(#|^)PermitRootLogin(yes|no)/PermitRootLogin no/' FILENAME 
# ............................^
```

I would suggest

```sh
sed -E '/PermitRootLogin/ s/.*/PermitRootLogin no/' FILENAME
```

which means: for any line containing the string "PermitRootLogin", replace the entire line with "PermitRootLogin no"

---

This one

```
sed -E 's/(#/|^/)PermitRootlogin(yes/|no/)/PermitRootLogin no/' FILENAME
```

shows a bit of a misunderstanding of the role of the `/` character in sed.

`/` is not a regex character, it's the delimiter for the `s` command to separate the regular expression, the replacement text, and the flags. See [3.3 The s Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) in the sed manual.

Comment: Your suggestion is very close to what I am looking for thank you very much. Only thing that I realized is that it will change every line that contains the "PermitRootLogin" line.
Is there a way to have it only look at a specific line within the file?

Comment: Have a look at [Can I find out which ssh key was used to access an account?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59943/27653)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '/^#?PermitRootLogin/{print "PermitRootLogin no"}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, checking condition if line starts with `#`(keeping it optional) followed by `PermitRootLogin` then using printing PermitRootLogin followed by `no` as per requirement.

***NOTE:*** In case you want to do inplace save the changes into same Input_file then run following: `awk '/^#?PermitRootLogin/{print "PermitRootLogin no""}' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file`

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/^#?(PermitRootLogin) +.*/\1 no/' file

PermitRootLogin no
PermitRootLogin no
PermitRootLogin no
```

Where input file is like this:

```sh
cat file

#PermitRootLogin yes
PermitRootLogin yes
#PermitRootLogin no
```

**Explanation:**

- `^`: Start
- `#?`: Match an optional `#`
- `(PermitRootLogin) +`: Match `PermitRootLogin` and capture in 1st group followed by 1+ space
- `.*`: Match anything till end of line
- `/\1 no/`: Replacement section to put value of capture group #1 followed by space and `no`

To save change inline into file use:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/^#?(PermitRootLogin) +.*/\1 no/' file
```

Comment: Not `#?` ? Are there some seds that don't have the `?` quantifier?

Comment: Basic `sed` without `-E` uses BRE where `?` and `{` need to be backslashed both. But you are using `-E` which however isn't POSIX-portable either.

Comment: Since `-E` has been used here so `{` doesn't need escaping. I can change it to `?` to make it even shorter

Comment: @anubhava: See [Can I find out which ssh key was used to access an account?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59943/27653)